# Certain person's comments showing up on my news feed, almost like I'm following them

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, a certain persons' comments are showing up on my new feed, almost like I'm following them, it's pretty much like whatever they do comes up on my news feed - even if there commenting on someone I don't know etc.

None of my other friends seem to be doing this, and for everyone else it's just rheir own posts that show. A friend was messing with my account when we were at the pub the other day, don't know if they did anything.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that these are not sponsored stories coming in between your news feed.

Visit the profile of the people and make sure that they are not in your friend list and that you are not following them. Explicitly change the subscription options for the particular users to unsubscribe if possible.

Are these people commenting and liking posts of your friends or people that you follow? If yes then change the subscription options for these particular friends or people that you follow.

And finally, are these posts about like and comments these people have made in a Group that you are a member of? If yes, then change the subscriptions option of the particular group or groups.